# Django + Ec2 -> Display "runserver" console output

Tags: django, apache, amazon-ec2

First off, apologies since I am about 150% positive there are a million better ways to phrase this question but I'm hitting a mental block as to how to describe this.

Using: Django, AWS EC2, Apache

Currently, I have a persistent Django app running on an AWS EC2 instance that is automatically run via WSGI. I want to know if there is a way to view the output you would normally see when you run "python manage.py runserver" from terminal.

That said, it's probably infinitely better to just ask using an image.

Something like this. http://puu.sh/gM9Md/c953d65398.png (Link because I can't imbed images yet)

I feel like the answer is extremely simple and I'm simply overlooking it, but I've been trying to figure this out for a good week now. I honestly just think I suck at googling for the right term.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a way to view it in a non file format? Eg, updates live. Like how it would literally appear if run with python from the terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [Apache access logs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#accesslog). The location of the log file changes from distribution to distribution, but assuming that you are using Ubuntu:

```
tail /var/log/apache2/access.log
```

If you want to watch it live, you can use:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log
```

You can press `Ctrl+C` to stop.